# Migrate MongoDB database from Raspberry Pi to Mac

Tags: database, mongodb, macos, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a MongoDB database running on a headless Raspberry Pi 3 which runs 32-bit Raspbian and MongoDB v2.4. I also have MongoDB running on my Mac, with 64-bit Big Sur and MongoDB v5.0.

I have data that I'd like to move from my Pi to my Mac. How could I accomplish this? Would it even be compatible?

In MongoDB v2, there's [db.copyDatabase()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) which has since been deprecated since v4. In MongoDB v4, there's [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#compatibility), <strike>but that's incompatible with v2</strike>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your raspberrypi dupm your db with:

```
mongodump --db=dbname --out=./
```

and send it to mac and on your mac restore it by :

```
mongorestore -d dbname -c collectionName  /place_of_dumpfile --drop
```

do it for each collection , or

```
 mongorestore -d dbname   /place_of_dumpfile --drop
```

Comment: I misunderstood! `mongodump` did in fact work on the Pi with MongoDB v2!